# Unable to set right path on Mac to read a file

Tags: macos, file, path

Trying to read a csv file with Python on my Mac.
The directory "Users" is an immediate subdirectory of the home directory "halen163@Jos-MacBook-Pro"
So, am using the os library and ~/ as the home directory
import os
file_to_open = os.path.expanduser('~/Users/halen163/Downloads/DAX.csv')
file = open(file_to_open)

Gives the error: No such file or directory: '/root/Users/halen163/Downloads/DAX.csv'

Already tried to add the home directory itself (instead of ~/) but did not work

Comment: Does `ls` work on that path?  (For Mac, I'd be more likely to expect `/Users/halen163/Downloads/DAX.csv`.)

Comment: Yes, ls is working on that path. if I drop the "tilde", I get the same error. message, just without 'root' in the path. The fact that the error message translates ~/ into "root", means something is right, but then does not recognise the absolute path

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `~` doesn't belong there, you just want `/Users/halen163/Downloads/DAX.csv`. The `~` basically means "insert home directory path here", so apparently what you're getting is the root user's home directory path stuck onto the halen163 user's home directory path, which doesn't make any sense.